# ldap spring security http basic auth

Tags: spring-security, ldap, basic-authentication

Can you please give me some links or solutions to manage my problem?
The problem is the follows. I have an LDAP server. How can I make http basic authorization through this LDAP server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up two different fetures of Spring Security:

- [LDAP Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap). Actual config described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-bean-config).
- HTTP Basic Authentication. This feature is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I made such a config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Then, BasicAuthenticationFilter

```
    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="BauthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="BauthenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

Entry point and manager were descrbed like that:

```
  <bean id="BauthenticationEntryPoint"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Name Of Your Realm"/>
</bean>
<bean id="BauthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And finally

```
    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>sAMAccountName={0}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <constructor-arg value=""/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When I try to access /index.jsp I shown an stadart http auth window that requesting me my username and password. When I type it into form and press Enter nothing goes on - an auth window just reloads and nothing more.

Where I made a mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: It will be better to create another question.